# Outlook Mail REST Api: How to get inline attachments only?

Tags: office365api, office365-restapi

Can't seem to figure out how to get only the inline attachments from an email. [The docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#attachment) say that the IsInline property is filterable, but when I send this request, I get both inline and non-inline files:

```
    public static function getInlineAttachments($access_token, $user_email, $message_id) {

    $attachmentsFilter = array(
        "\$select" => "Id,Name,ContentType,Size,IsInline,Microsoft.OutlookServices.FileAttachment/ContentId",
        "\$filter" => "IsInline eq true"
    );

    $url = "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/Me/Messages/" . $message_id . '/attachments?' . http_build_query($attachmentsFilter);

    return self::makeApiCall($access_token, $user_email, "GET", $url);
}
```

There is an alternative, to only get meta-data about the attachments and then query the API to only get the inline ones by Id, but if you get a lot of inline attachments then the GET request max length is exceeded and therefore the request fails. There is another option to batch attachments in several consecutive requests, but this is also not ideal.

So, anybody having a good solution to this problem?

UPDATE:
I can't seem to filter by attachment Id or Name as well. It seems that even the workarounds that I thought I could use will not work. I must be missing something...